# Is an overlay page like this image possible with .NET MAUI?

Tags: .net, maui

You can drag it down and it will dismiss the view.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for is "modal". Afaik these modals can be closed natively on ios by dragging (at least last time I checked.) but couldn't find a native way to do it on maui.

But here is a solution you can build up for your need:

Navigate to your page like this using Shell.

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("/modalpage");
```

**ModalPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage
    x:Class="MauiApp.ModalPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Title="Modal Page"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    Shell.PresentationMode="Modal">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
        </Grid>

        <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="LightGray">

        <VerticalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Down" Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped" />
        </VerticalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

            <Label
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Set your ContentPage background to `Transparent` and `Shell.PresentationMode="Modal"`

I've created a grid with 2 rows, so I can catch the tap gestures on the first row, which in this case a fully transparent row where I can see my previous page.

You can do a swipe-to-close action too. But this time you are swiping the bottom layout, so the VerticalStackLayout gets the SwipeGestureRecognizer

**ModalPage.cs**

```
 private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
 }

 private void SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
 {
     Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
 }
```